# creating a gradle dependency - remove access to its own dependencies

Tags: android, maven, gradle, dependencies, okhttp

An unreleased android library I am working on has a third party networking library in it - OkHttp in this case.

Projects that use this library as a dependency also are now able to create objects with that networking library.

Can I limit or disable access to the networking library contained within my library?

Comment: What is your end objective? Even if you restrict your library users from accessing OkHttp through your library, they can still add OkHttp as a compile dependency and use it. So what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Are you packaging your android library as an aar? Are you packaging OkHttp with your aar? or is it a transitive dependency defined in a pom.xml?

Comment: @RaGe I expect people to already have OkHttp as a a compile dependency already, or that they might consider adding it. There is also the possibility that they will be adding/using a different version of OkHttp so I don't want them to use the version in my library. My library is packaged however bintray packages it, and people implement it as a dependency from gradle. OkHttp is a gradle dependency of my library

Comment: How are you creating your aar? are you using the gradle-aar plugin?

Answer (score 2):

You could make the dependency `transitive` however if your code hits the missing code inside their app it will fail ClassNotFound or MethodNotFound

```
dependencies {
    compile('com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0') {
        transitive = false
    }
}
```

Short of that once the code is packaged with your lib it's available to anyone who wants to use it from your lib.

This still won't solve the problem as you would like but you could use proguard to rename the okhttp classes. Users of your lib could still call the okhttp classes but they would be renamed by proguard to something like a,b,c,...

Comment: Can you tell me more about the transitive property? I'm not sure about what limitation this introduces, so my library makes heavy use of OkHttp3, if they include my library will it still work with OkHttp3 methods?  Secondly, if they import OkHttp3 because they also happen to use it, will this avoid any conflicts?

Comment: This doesn't seem to get me to the outcome I want, I have a project that uses my dependency and add OkHttp via gradle, yet it still has access to OkHttp methods. I was wondering if there was a way to make it inaccessible

Comment: Added comment about proguard to rename the classes, but once they are packaged with the lib you can't truely prevent user's of your lib from accessing the classes

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is **shade** the dependency. Here's a description from a blog post about [shading dependencies in Gradle](https://forgegradle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user-guide/shading/):

> To Shade a library is to take the contents files of said library, put
>   them in your own jar, and change their package.This is different from
>   packaging which is simply shipping the libraries files in side your
>   own jar without relocating them to a different package. The term
>   fatjar is commonly used to refer to jars that have the application as
>   well as its dependencies packaged or shaded into them.

It's easy to do for smaller libraries. I could image it might be difficult for a large library like OkHttp. You can do it manually by simply copying the files into your project and changing the package. There are also [some scripts](https://gist.github.com/arcao/16d51cce70dadec54bef) that will do it automatically. They usually use [Jar Jar Links](https://github.com/shevek/jarjar).

Comment: Changing the package does not prevent access to these classes does it? Makes them obscure and hence unlikely to be used, but they're still available for use by an application using this jar.

Answer (score 1):

Normally be default you don't have the dependencies like that:

```
compile rootProject.ext.okhttp
```

compiled in your jar only your sources are. So OkHttp classes will not be in your lib.

I have exactly the same case. I use gradle to build and upload to maven.
You can check [here](https://github.com/apptik/jus/tree/master/stack/jus-okhttp)

So if your intention is to have the exact dept version in the package and to be hidden you just need to include it in you project as a module and to change some things like the package of OkHttp to avoid conflicts and also the access to currenly public okhttp members. OkHttp is using Okio so you may want to privatize it too.

Note that this kind of shadowing + hiding functionality of the shadowed class can be useful for framework dependencies(ensuring all depts in runtime available) but it is increasing the size of your libs and will not be the best option for apps using your lib as they anyway ensure packaging required depts in the apk.

Comment: so, you are saying I need to clone OkHttp, turn it into a Jar, and copy the jar into my project? And that this will prevent people that use my dependency from accessing OkHttp functions?

Comment: you just need to include it in you project as a module and to change some things like the package of OkHttp to avoid conflicts and also the access to currenly public okhttp members. OkHttp is using Okio so you may want to privatize it too. But why do you really want to do that. This will just increase the size of your lib I don't see any other advantage.

Comment: moved comments to the answer